# Is there a shortcut to change sorting (lexicographic/relevance) of IntelliJ suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

The image says everything. Is there a keyboard shortcut to change this order, without having to click this little icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to assign a shortcut yet. You can file a feature request for that at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com. Please specify why you need this.

Comment: Thanks, gonna do that. The reason i think it would be useful is that, sometimes we have to alternate very often the sorting method, let's say when creating an object an setting it's variables through many setXxx methods, where usually/sometimes we write the setter methods in alphabetical order, but the content suggestions inside setter methods are more correctly shown when sorted by relevance.